# WSO2 ESB on JBoss

Tags: jboss, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to deploy WSO2ESB on JBoss AS in order to enable transactions.

Up to know I have not found any official guide for that.

1) What is the latest version of JBoss supported by WSO2ESB 4.5.1?
2) Is there some official guide I could follow? (I have found the following blog but it dates back on 2010: http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2010/03/deploying-wso2esb300-jboss510ga)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no longer have to deploy WSO2 ESB in an application server (which supports distributed transactions) in order to have a transaction manager to be employed in handling distributed transactions. We, by default, ship a transaction manager implementation (atomikos, and this will be the default transaction manager if there's no other container provided transaction manager is available) with WSO2 ESB which provides you the complete stack of functionalities related to distributed transactions. Therefore, it's just gonna be a matter of using the trasnaction mediator in your ESB configurations without having to go through much hassle.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Prabath

Comment: Thank you Prabath. I did find a sample in some blog using the Atomikos implementation and it works OK!

Answer (score 0):

In current versions WSO2 does not support deploying WSO2 ESB in application servers. You can use standalone product straight away.

Comment: The product documentation in the Transaction mediator mentions the need to deploy the ESB into some application server that supports transactions (JBoss). Am i wrong ? http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Transactions